# VirtualBox and default machine directory in Debian

Tags: debian, virtualbox

The version of my VirtualBox is:

```
6.1.28-147628~Debian~bullseye
```

...and the extension pack is the latest version.

I copied my `VirtualBox\ VMs/` directory to `/` and introduced the given directory to VirtualBox as the default machine directory, but when I open VirtualBox it can't show my VMs.

```
root@debian:~# ls /VirtualBox\ VMs/
 centos_           'debian bare stretch big data'  'freebsd 32 10_'  'kali 64_'    vm                     'win xp sp3 stable'
 debian_            FreeBSD                'GNS3 IOU VM'      mikrotik_   'win 7 32 stable for programmming'
'debian bare stretch'  'FreeBSD 10 (pf for chpert)'    'kali 64'     'MS SQL server'  'win 98'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit `$HOME/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml` and change the `src` attribute for all your VMs under `<MachineRegistry></MachineRegistry>`.

This could probably work (replace `username` with your actual username):

```bsh
cp -a $HOME/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml $HOME/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml.backup
sed -i 's/\/home\/username//g` $HOME/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml
```

For Debian this would be:

```bsh
cp -a $HOME/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml $HOME/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml.backup
sed -i 's/\/home\/username//g` $HOME/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml
```

Comment: Oh, `cp: cannot stat '/home/mohsen/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml': No such file or directory`

Comment: I've updated the answer.